# IBM Domino Sometimes Agent Runs Slowly

Tags: lotus-domino

When run agent, sometimes meet the error like "HTTP Server: Execution time limit exceeded by Agent xxx". But if run again, it would run correctly. Is it means that the agent blocked by other tasks? Where should I research the reason? Code like below:

```
Set tDb = New NotesDatabase(db.Server, "test\Test.nsf")
Set tView = tDb.GetView("TestView")
Set tDoc = tView.GetFirstDocument
lastTest = After(tDoc.Name(0)) 
lastName = tDoc.Name(0)
curName = lastName
Open dirLoc & Replace(lastTest) & ".html" For Output As #1
For i = 0 To 6
    Print #1, headerArray(i)
Next
While Not tDoc Is Nothing
    curTest = After(tDoc.Name(0)) 
    curName = tDoc.Name(0)  
    If lastTest <> curTest Then
        Print #1, footerStr
        Close #1
        Open dirLoc & Replace(curTest) & ".html" For Output As #1
        For i = 0 To 6
            Print #1, headerArray(i)
        Next
    End If
    Set dateAssigned = New NotesDateTime(tDoc.Completed(0))
    timeDiff = todaysDate.TimeDifference(dateAssigned) / 3600 / 24
    If timeDiff <= 10 Then
        Print #1, repeatArr(0)
        ... ...
        Print #1, repeatArr(14)
    End If
    lastName = curName
    lastTest =  After(tDoc.Name(0))
    Set tDoc = tView.GetNextDocument(tDoc)
Wend    
Print #1, footerStr
Close #1
```

Comment: What does the agent do? Can you post the code?

Comment: Also, what is the "Web agent and web services timeout" setting on the Domino Web Engine tab for your server?  That's different from the setting that Per Henrik mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the "Max LotusScript/Java execution time:" on the server document in order for your agent to be allowed to run longer.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! The agent will complete in 1-2 minutes under normal condition. And the Max LotusScript execution time is 30 minutes. But sometimes the agent can't complete in 30 minutes and show the error. Seems like other job blocked this agent? But I can't find the position to see job queue/job status.

Comment: FYI: That setting is for agents run under the AMGR task. The error message indicates that this is a web agent run under the HTTP task. I believe the setting for max HTTP agent execution time is on the Domino Web Engine tab, and it is typically set to a much shorter time than the AMGR limit.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what the agent does this cannot be answered. I suggest adding some logging using [OpenNTF OpenLog](https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/OpenLog/summary) or something like it so you can see what is taking the time in the agent.